# Python sockets/port forwarding

Tags: python, linux, bash, sockets, networking

I've written server and client programs with Python.

**Server.py**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5555

sock.bind((host, port))

sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

data = "Hello!"
data = bytes(data, 'utf-8')

conn.send(data)

sock.close()
```

**Client.py on Linux**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5555

sock.connect((host, port))

data = sock.recv(2048)

data = str(data, "utf-8")

print(data)

sock.close()
```

When I run the server and then the client on my local machine (a Linux Mint), it works correctly. I got "Hello!" in bash, and everything is fine. BUT when I ran my client program on another machine (a Windows 8) and ran it (previously I ran server on Linux, of course, and change IP address in client to my static Linux mint's IP) it says:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it

**client.py on Windows**

```
import socket
    
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
host = "here is my static ip"
port = 5555
    
sock.connect((host, port))
    
data = sock.recv(2048)
    
data = str(data, "utf-8")
    
print(data)
    
sock.close()
```

I must say that I had done port forwarding in my router settings on port 5555. Earlier, I had done same thing to port 80 and my own site worked correctly, but now it doesn't work to 5555 with Python sockets! Why? I can't get it! And one more thing: I tried to change the port to 80 in my server and client files, but it didn't work too. PLease, help.

Comment: Try to replace `socket.gethostname()` with an empty string in the server script.

Comment: @Qeek thank you very much! I am extremely new in python so can you please explain why does empty string work correctly and name of host doesn't?

Comment: If both of your machines are located in your private network, you don't need to configure router. Have you checked that Windows machine does not have Firewall block for this particular port?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to change the `socket.gethostname()` in the server script to the empty string (or just directly call `socket.bind(('', port))`).

Your problem is not in Python but in the usage of sockets generally. When you create a socket, you just prepare your process to receive/send some data from/to another process.

### Server

The first step for creating a socket is to specify what kind of protocol will be used for communication between those processes. In your case it is the `socket.AF_INET` which is constant for use of IP protocol and the `socket.SOCK_STREAM` is specify reliable stream-oriented service. The reliable stream-oriented service means that you want to be sure that every single sent byte will be delivered to the other side and nothing can be lost during the communication (the underlying OS will use the TCP protocol for that). From this point we are using the IPv4 protocol (because we set the `socket.AF_INET`).

The second step is `bind` it to an address. The `bind` process assigns an address where you expect a client will join (with your socket's settings it's a IP address and the TCP port). Your PC has multiple IP address (well, at least two). It always has `127.0.0.1`, which is called "callback" and works only when your applications communicate on the same PC (that is you Linux - Linux scenario in the question), and then you have your external IP address, for communication with other computers (let's pretend it is `10.0.0.1`).

When you call `socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5555))`, you're setting the socket to listen only for communication from the same PC. If you call `socket.bind(('10.0.0.1', 5555))`, then the socket setting is ready to receive data targeted to the `10.0.0.1` address.

But what if you have 10 IPs or more and you want to receive everything (with the right TCP port)? For those scenarios you can leave the IP address in `bind()` empty, and it does exactly what you want.

With Python's version of `bind()`, you can also enter a "computer name" instead of the concrete IP. The `socket.gethostname()` call returns your computer's name. The problem is in the translation of "computer name" to the IP which Python performs behind your back. The translation has some rules but generally your "computer name" can be translated into any IP address which you have set on your computer. In your case, the your computer's name is converted into `127.0.0.1`, and that's why communication works only between processes on the same computer.

After `socket.bind()`, you have the socket ready to use but it is still "inactive". The call to `socket.listen()` activates the socket and causes it to wait until it receives an attempted connection. When a socket receives a new connection request, it will put it into a queue and wait for processing.

That's what `socket.accept()` does. It pulls the connection request from the queue, accepts it, and establishes the stream (remember the `socket.SOCK_STREAM` when you set up the socket) between the server and the client. The new stream is actually a new socket, but is ready to communicate with other side.

What happened with the old socket? Well, it's still alive, and you can call `socket.listen()` again to get another stream (connection).

### How is it possible to have multiple sockets on the same port?

Every connection within computer's network is defined by flow which is 5-item tuple of:

- L4 protocol (usually TCP or UDP)
- Source IP address
- Source L4 port
- Destination IP address
- Destination L4 port

When you create a new connection with a client, the flow can look like this: `(TCP, 192.168.0.1, 12345, 10.0.0.1, 55555)`. Just for clarification, the server's response flow is `(TCP,  10.0.0.1, 55555, 192.168.0.1, 12345)`, but it isn't important for us. If you create another connection with a client, that it will differ at source TCP port (if you do it from another computer that it will differ also at the source IP). Only from this information you can distinguish every connection created to your computer.

When you create a server socket in your code and call `socket.listen()`, it listens for any flow with this pattern `(TCP, *, *, *, 55555)` (the * means "match everything"). So when you get a connection with `(TCP, 192.168.0.1, 12345, 10.0.0.1, 55555)`, then `socket.accept()` creates another socket which works only with this one concrete flow while the old socket carries on  accepting new connections which haven't yet been established.

When the operating system receives a packet, it looks in the packet and checks the flow. At this point, several scenarios can take place:

- The packet's flow matches all 5 items exactly (without usage of `*`). Then the packet's content is delivered to the queue associated with that socket (you're reading the queue when you call `socket.recv()`).
- The packet's flow matched socket with associated flow contains `*` then it is considered as new connection and you can call `scoket.accept()`.
- The operating system doesn't contain open socket which would match the flow. In that case the OS  refuse connection (or just ignore the packet it depends on firewall settings).

Probably an example can clarify these scenarios. The operating system has something like a table where it maps flows to sockets. When you call `socket.bind()`, it will assign a flow to the socket. After the call, the table can look like this:

```
+=====================================+========+
|                Flow                 | Socket |
+=====================================+========+
| (TCP, *, *, *, 55555)               |      1 |
+-------------------------------------+--------+
```

When it receive a packet with flow `(TCP, 1.1.1.1, 10, 10.0.0.1, 10)` then it won't match any flow (last port won't match). So, the connection is refused. If it receives a packet with flow `(TCP, 1.1.1.1, 10, 10.0.0.1, 55555)`, the packet is delivered to the socket `1` (because there is a match). The `socket.accept()` call creates a new socket and record in the table.

```
+=====================================+========+
|                Flow                 | Socket |
+=====================================+========+
| (TCP, 1.1.1.1, 10, 10.0.0.1, 55555) |      2 |
+-------------------------------------+--------+
| (TCP, *, *, *, 55555)               |      1 |
+-------------------------------------+--------+
```

Now you have 2 sockets for 1 port. Every received packet which matches the flow associated with the socket `2` also matches the flow associated with socket `1` (on the contrary, it does not apply). It's not a problem because the socket `2` has a preciser match (is doesn't use the `*`), so any data with that flow will be delivered to socket `2`.

### How to serve multiple connections

If you want to implement a "real" server, your application should be able to process multiple connections without restarting. There are 2 basic approaches:

1. Sequential processing

   ```
   try:
       l = prepare_socket()
       while True:
           l.listen()
           s, a = socket.accept()
           process_connection(s) # before return you should call s.close()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       l.close()
   ```

   In this case, you can process only one client while others clients have to wait for accept. If the `process_connection()` takes too long, then others clients will timeout.
2. Parallel processing

   ```
   import threading
   threads = []

   try:
       l = prepare_socket()
       while True:
           l.listen()
           s, a = socket.accept()
           t = threading.Thread(target=process_connection, s)
           threads.append(t)
           t.start()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       for t in threads:
           t.join()
       l.close()
   ```

   Now when you receive a new connection, it will create a new thread so that every connection is processed in parallel. The main disadvantage of this solution is that you have to solve common troubles with threading (like access to shared memory, deadlocks etc.).

Beware that the above snippets are only examples, and are not complete! For example, they don't contain code for graceful exit on unexpected exceptions.

### Servers in Python

Python also contains a module called [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html), which contains shortcuts for creating servers in Python. You can find examples of how to use it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example).

### Client

With the client, it's much more simpler than with the server. You just have to create a socket with some settings (same as server side), and then tell it where the server is (what its IP and TCP port are). This is accomplished through the `socket.connect()` call. As a bonus, it also establishes the stream between your client and server, so from this point you can communicate.

---

You can find more information about sockets at the [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It's written for usage with C, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: But how does old socket (I have created firstly) live at some port while new one (that deals with certain connection already) is existing at the same port? How do they not interfere?

Comment: @AlexanderMueller I expand the answer with explanations of how multiple sockets on the same port work.

Comment: 1. When I call `socket.listen()` it listens to  `(TCP, *, *, *, 55555)` pattern. So current socket is on port 55555, cause we specified it when we `socket.bind()`. When something is coming new socket is created and it is on the same port (we can guess it if we look into new certain flow new socket works with: `(TCP, 192.168.0.1, 12345, 10.0.0.1, 55555)`). Okay, old socket listens to new connections, but new works with certain one, but they are on the same port! Port is a program, isn't it?

Comment: Therefore one program works simultaneously as listener and as handler for certain connection. But I don't think so :c 
2. You said that "The flow doesn't mach any socket so it will refuse connection."  If we have some packet from internet it must have destination address all (it's condition to get this packet at all) but you said, that we don't see any socket there, in the packet.

Comment: Also, if everything I am interested in described in the book you specified - just say it! And I will read from now on without any questions. Thank you again :)

Comment: @AlexanderMueller I've tried to fill some example about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem months ago and also wasn't able to do port forwarding. I found a way out of port forwarding **Ngrock**

For your information what **Ngrock** does is it is a useful utility to create secure tunnels to locally hosted applications using a reverse proxy. It is a utility to expose any locally hosted application over the web

For How To use it, please see the steps shown below :

If you are in **Mac** write this command in your **terminal** to download ngrock

```
brew install ngrok
```

For **windows**

```
choco install ngrok
```

After installing You need need to sign up on the [Ngrok website](https://dashboard.ngrok.com) 
You will get your Ngrock **authentication token** then paste this command in the terminal

For **Mac** and **Windows**

```
ngrok config add-authtoken <token>
```

Now that Ngrock is all setup you can start a tunnel using

```
ngrok tcp <Your Port Number Used In Server.py>
ngrok tcp 5321
```

****Note** :** Please Give the command inside the directory in which the Python Socket Server File in Located

That's it Your Socket can connect you any computer over the internet anywhere in the world

If You are still struggling to see the detailed explanation in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hs7GLsHQCPQ)
You can also refer **ngrock** documentation [here](https://ngrok.com/docs)