# What are the host and the port of a socket connection (Python's socket.socket) through TCP tunnel?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Let's say I have this Python snippet on a server

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
# ...
```

This server should be accessible via TCP tunneling. I can access the server via ssh (`ssh server@host-of-tcp.io -p <port>`).

Now what are the `host` and `port` parameters in such a case? It cannot be the parameters of TCP tunnel but I do not have any other idea what to pick or what I should do outside of my python code to find out.

Comment: Does [Python sockets/port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45101773/5821790) help?

Comment: Maaaybe.... After using '' as host and a non-privileged port as a port, running it on the server (which is a Raspberry Pi), it returns SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2 and closes the connection.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but when I have to use tunelling in `ssh` to acces database on server which works on port `localhost:3306` (so I can't access it normally) then I don't have to change ports in database or in my local program. I have to only run `ssh` with option `-L 3306:3306` and then my local program is connectin with local `ssh` on port `3306` (first `3306` in option), it sends it to `ssh` on server and it connects with database on port `3306` (second `3306` in option)

Comment: BTW : if I have database on local computer which also uses port `3306` then I use ie. `-L  13306:3306` and then in local program I use `13306` and program uses port `13306` to connect with local `ssh`, it sends it to `ssh` on server which uses `3306` to connect with database on server.